# Russian Visa Duration

Tags: visas, russia

I have a Russian 3 year multiple entry visa, on which is written "за шесть месяцев" (for six months). The police here say that the visa duration is 3 months on, 3 months off, but have agreed to check on this.

On the Russian consulate site, it also says 3 months off, 3 months on (90 days in a 180 day period), but this is a contradiction of what is written on the visa.

I have found an article titled, "Historic Visa Agreement Enters Into Force September 9, 2012" (http://moscow.usembassy.gov/pr_visas-082912.html), which states that,

> For Americans in Russia, the agreement lifts the previous restriction
>   limiting stays in Russia to 90 days within any given 180-day
>   period—just like Russian travelers, they will now be permitted stays
>   of up to six months. In addition, “exit visas” will no longer be
>   necessary in the case of U.S. citizens who lose their passports while
>   in Russia. (Russian citizens may already exit the United States
>   without an exit visa). U.S. citizens with current Russian visas are
>   reminded that they are still subject to the terms and dates of the
>   visas already in their possession.

Unfortunately, this is on the U.S. Embassy site and not the Russian Embassy/Consulate site. Even worse, it is written in English, which no one here knows.

(http://moscow.usembassy.gov/russian-visas.html)

> In October 2007, the Russian government made significant changes to
>   its rules regarding the length of stay permitted to most foreign
>   visitors.  Visas issued for 3 years allow for a 6-month uninterrupted
>   stay in the country. The break between the intervals may be as short
>   as one calendar day.

I suppose, then, **I am asking if anyone can find an official document stating that a 6 month duration is valid, and especially something in Russian?**

Answer (score 4):

Found [this press-release](http://russian.moscow.usembassy.gov/pr_visas-082912.html) on russian version of the US embassy in Moscow (simply add `russia.` to the URL of the release:

> Для американцев **соглашение снимает ограничение максимального
>   пребывания в России до 90 дней** в течение любого 180-дневного периода
>   действия визы. Так же, как и россиянам в США, им теперь будет
>   разрешено пребывание в России **до шести месяцев**.

As you stated, it says that the previous restriction is lifted away.

**Update:**

[On Russian Consulate in San-Francisco](http://www.consulrussia.org/ru/visa.html) you can find a document with the Aggreement's text ([direct link](http://www.russianembassy.org/sites/default/files/documents/Agreement%20in%20Russian%20092012.doc)):

> 3. Гражданам каждой из Сторон, как правило, выдаются многократные визы для пребывания на срок **не более 6 месяцев с даты каждого въезда**,
>      действительные в течение 36 месяцев с даты выдачи, при условии
>      соблюдения принципа взаимности: Российской Федерацией - деловые,
>      частные, гуманитарные и туристические визы и Соединенными Штатами
>      Америки - визы В1/В2.

It states that you can be in Russia up to 6 months **since last entry date**, and visa is valid for the 36 months (3 years). So, yes, you are right in the conclusions that you can stay in Russia for 6 months in a row.

**Update #2:**

Консульский департамент МИД России (Russian consulate Department) site contains the agreement text:

[Нота МИД от 08.11.2011 №46197/кд](http://www.kdmid.ru/docs.aspx?lst=country_wiki&it=/Nota_%E2%84%96_46197kd_081111.aspx)

[Regulation base for the US-Russia relations](http://www.kdmid.ru/docs.aspx?lst=country_wiki&it=/%D0%9D%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%20%D0%B4%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%85%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85%20%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D1%81%20%D0%A1%D0%A8%D0%90.aspx)

Hope this helps for the police check, good luck with that. Don't give away your passport and call the consulate as soon as you can. Do not offer the bribe.

Comment: "не более 6 месяцев с даты каждого въезда" - literally, "not more than 6 months" Maybe in Russian this means, "6 months"? That works about the U.S. embassy site though.

Comment: Not `not more than 6 months`, but `not more than 6 months since each entrance date`